# Django Class-based views: displaying queryset using choices from a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django and as such I have a few gaps in my knowledge, particularly with regards to the get_context_data() in views. My aim is to try and make use of the DRY aspect of Django so that I have a list of categories on my webpage and each category reveals a list of posts that fall under  it. To achieve this, I have a ListView and DetailView class (shown below). Note, the categories and posts are all objects of the same model.
My issues are the following:

1. I would like to display only some of the posts in my ListView not all of them. Is there a dynamic way to do this?
2. In my DetailView, I want to display a list of posts but from a single choice, for eg say choice1 is selected when creating a post, then only all posts with choice 1 selected will be displayed. I would like to do that dynamically, currently its hardcoded to only display choice1. I have tried to use the get_context_data() to do this but this only outputs a queryset in my template which leads me to problem 3
3. My HTML file currently displays all posts of choice1 as a QuerySet but not the actual content

Views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post 
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'   
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    list_of_relevant_articles = Post.objects.filter(choice = "choice1")
    context.update({'list_of_relevant_articles': list_of_relevant_articles})
    return context
```

Models.py

```
POST_CHOICES = (
    ('choice1','CHOICE1'),
    ('choice2', 'CHOICE2'),
    ('choice3','CHOICE3'),
    ('choice4','CHOICE4'),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices = POST_CHOICES, default ='choice1')


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog-post', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Html file

```
{% block content %}
<!-- This for loop does not output anything but I believe i need one to iterate through 
 a queryset-->
{% for post in object_list %}
    {{ list_of_relevant_articles }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1

you can use `context['posts'] = context['posts'][:3]` and a normal loop in template, but it is better to use pagination in general.

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post 
    template_name = 'blog/post.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'   
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = context['posts'][:3]
        return context
```

```html
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

The other way is do not use `get_context_data` and inside the template use slicing like:

`{% for post in posts|slice:":2" %}`

### 2, 3

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/detail.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = "choice"
    slug_field = "choice"
    context_object_name = 'posts'   
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Post.objects.filter(choice=self.kwargs.get("choice"))
```

```html
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('post/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('post/<str:choice>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

so in the browser: `.../post/choice2/`, `.../post/choice3/`, ...